# What does the NORM.INV function in excel actually do?

Tags: normal-distribution, excel

I understand that it does the opposite of NORMDIST function and returns a normal cumulative distribution. But is there a formula that it uses? Is it using the Quantile function?

Comment: This *is* the quantile function.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22NORM.INV%22.